# .env.sh in craft-scrips

Tags: cache

I'm having trouble setting the variables of the env.sh file for craft-sctipts.

I getting an error: `File /common/defaults.sh is missing, aborting.` when I try to clear the cache using a cronjob pointing to the clear cache script.

My variables are set in the env.sh file, which is in the scripts directory.
`LOCAL_ROOT_PATH="/domains/mydomain.ca/"`
`REMOTE_ROOT_PATH="/domains/mydomain.ca/"`

The scripts are in `/domains/mydomain.ca/scripts/` directory.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Those root paths aren't relative to your project root, they are meant to be absolute system paths - are the `/domains` folders at the root of your system?

Comment: Yah... /domains is the top level directory (Shared Media Temple hosting).

Answer (score 1):

The other error Im getting is `dirname: command not found`.

I was able to solve this issue by just manually setting the DIR variable in the script I needed to use. There is probably a better way....